# Persistent Login with Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am coding a new application using the Facebook C# SDK 6.0. So far I managed well to do all the features required. There is still one thing I am stuck with through.

Now, in my application, the user always login through a web browser component in the winform.

I would like to stock in the database the login details of the user so he doesn't need to login with the web browser component everytime he launches the application.

I created a settings form where the user can key in his login details. What should I save in the database to do the requests simply afterwards in another form? Is it possible to login without using the web browser?

Thank you for your help,
Thomas

Comment: I think you need to read the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) docs again - what you're suggesting is not supported and is explicitly against policy

Comment: Thanks for you insight. I am reading about authentication in Facebook. I was thinking it could be possible maybe with the SDK. I will use the long-lived token access and ask the user to login again when it expired.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with HttpWebRequest? can you pass the link of the SDK ?

Comment: Hi DotNeter, This is the website of the Facebook C# SDK: http://csharpsdk.org. So far I did not try with the HttpWebRequest since I am using the SDK. I think I will try it.